# Integral of GeneratingFunction

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know that GeneratingFunction can be used to compute the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ of a sequence $(a_n)_n$ via

```
GeneratingFunction[a[n],n,x]
```

I also know that polynomial (in $n$) coefficients of the general term $a_n$ of the sequence result in an expression involving derivatives of the generating function, e.g.

```
GeneratingFunction[n a[n],n,x]
(* x (GeneratingFunction^(0,0,1))[a[n],n,x] *)
```

This does not seem to happen with rational (in $n$) coefficients, which would lead to indefinite integrals of the generating function. For example I would expect the input

```
GeneratingFunction[a[n]/(n + 1), n, x]
```

to result in

```
(*1/x Integrate[GeneratingFunction[a[n],n,y],{y,0,x}]*)
```

or

```
(*1/x GeneratingFunction^(0,0,-1))[a[n],n,x]*)
```

but this does not seem to be the case.

**I thus have the following question:** Is it possible to get Mathematica to compute the generating function of a linear combination of lagged values of $a_n$ with rational (in $n$) coefficients in terms of derivatives and integrals of the generating function of the sequence $(a_n)_n$?

Comment: `GeneratingFunction[a[n]/(n + 1), n, x] === 
 1/x Integrate[GeneratingFunction[a[n], n, y], {y, 0, x}]` is `False`. Are you sure that it lands there ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Blackbird. That's what I obtain through fairly easy manual rearrangement of the series defining the generating function. The first example that came to my mind, $a_n=(n+1)^{-k}$ supports the claim. The question is, how do I get Mathematica to recognise the equality and, ideally, to simplify the LHS of your equation accordingly into the RHS.

Comment: `GeneratingFunction^(0,0,1)` is not recognized by `M`, what do you mean by this ?

Comment: I mean the derivative with respect to the third argument, $x$ in this case.

Comment: For me `GeneratingFunction[n a[n],n,x]` evaluates to `x GeneratingFunction[(1+n)a[1+n], n, x]`.  Which version of Mma are you using? (I'm using 9.)

Comment: @AndrewMacFie: I'm using Mma v8.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, I handle coefficients of the form

$$ \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}, $$

where $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ are polynomials in the index symbol $n$, $\deg(p(n)) < \deg(q(n))$, and all of the roots of $q(n)$ are negative integers.
If $\deg(p(n)) \geq \deg(q(n))$, we may have to differentiate a power series, and as I mentioned in my comment, *Mathematica* 9 doesn't handle that conveniently.
If $q(n)$ has positive integer roots, we have to handle undefined expressions and things are more complicated.

First, some setup code

```
(* http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32531/how-to-unprotect-generatingfunction *)
GeneratingFunction;
protected = Unprotect[GeneratingFunction];

(* what can usually be used as a variable, according to 
    ref/message/General/ivar *)
variablePattern = Except[_String | _?NumberQ | _Plus | _Times | 
    _Sum | _Product | _^_Integer];

arg2 = Sequence[n:variablePattern, x:variablePattern];
```

Now, we add a downvalue for `GeneratingFunction` which expands $p(n)/q(n)$ into partial fractions.

```
GeneratingFunction[expr_, arg2, 
    opts:OptionsPattern[]] /; expr =!= Apart[expr, n] :=
    GeneratingFunction[Apart[expr, n], n, x, opts];
```

I will assume that the coefficients are now in the form

$$ \frac{c}{(n + k)^j}.$$

To go from here, in the next rule we add a downvalue saying

$$ \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n+k} f(n) x^n = x^{-k} \int_0^x t^{k-1} \left( \sum_{n \geq 0} f(n) t^n \right) dt,$$

which gets used repeatedly until $j=0$.

```
GeneratingFunction[expr_ * (n_ + k_?Positive)^(j_?Negative), arg2, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := With[
    {t = Unique[]},
    x^(-k) * Integrate[t^(k-1) * GeneratingFunction[expr * (n + k)^(j + 1),
        n, t, opts], {t, 0, x}]
];
```

And we're done.

```
Protect[Evaluate[protected]];
```