# How to unprotect GeneratingFunction

Tags: programming, packages, customization, downvalues, built-in-symbols

I'm trying to add custom downvalues for `GeneratingFunction`, and to do so I thought I just had to `Unprotect` it.  However, that doesn't work:

```
Unprotect[GeneratingFunction]
```

> ```
> {"GeneratingFunction"}
> ```

```
GeneratingFunction[2] = 3
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[3]:= Set::write: Tag GeneratingFunction in 
> GeneratingFunction[2] is Protected. >>
>
>  3
> ```

```
GeneratingFunction[2]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[4]:= GeneratingFunction::argmu: GeneratingFunction
> called with 1 argument; 3 or more arguments are expected. >>
>
> GeneratingFunction[2]
> ```

I'm running *Mathematica* 9 64 bit on Linux.  What do I need to do to really remove protection from this symbol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GeneratingFunction` by default is not a function: it is a stub which loads corresponding .mx package. You can see this with the following:

```
ClearAttributes[GeneratingFunction,{Protected,ReadProtected}]
OwnValues@GeneratingFunction
```

> {HoldPattern[GeneratingFunction] :>
>   System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[GeneratingFunction], 
>       Hold[GeneratingFunction, GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode], 
>       "Discrete`GeneratingFunction`"] /; System`Dump`TestLoad}

The functions `ClearAttributes` and `OwnValues` have `Hold*` attributes and so the above code does not evaluate `GeneratingFunction`. After first evaluation it's `Attributes` and `Options` are redefined by the loaded package:

```
GeneratingFunction;
Attributes[GeneratingFunction]
Options[GeneratingFunction]
```

> {Protected, ReadProtected}
>
> {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, GenerateConditions -> False,   Method ->
>   Automatic, VerifyConvergence -> True}

I do not know why we can't see any top-level code for `GeneratingFunction` with `Information`, but `Tracing` its evaluation reveals a bunch of top-level functions it uses:

```
Trace[GeneratingFunction[1, n, x], TraceInternal -> True]
```

For the original discussion of this issue see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649618/590388) by Sasha (Wolfram Research) with comments under it.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why `Unprotect`does not work (bug, feature?). The following does work though:

```
ClearAttributes[GeneratingFunction, Protected]
GeneratingFunction[2] = 3
GeneratingFunction[2]
```

> 3

Comment: hmm, that's not working for me

Comment: clearing the attribute, attempting to set a value, receiving an error, then clearing the attribute again and setting a value seems to work though

Comment: @Andrew May be the situation is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5649618/590388)?

Comment: @AndrewMacFie: You need to run it twice so Wolfram can confirm your intentions with absolute certainty.  ;-)  On a serious note, what kind of "feature" is that?!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov ah yes... this question is very similar to that one